# Icons and content are not showing similar in different manufacturer devices with same resolution and same ppi

Tags: android, difference, screen-resolution, oneplus7

I am testing my app and I figure out that my app is looking different in two different manufacturer devices with same resolution.
I have two devices as below and there are too many differences in my app regarding their icon size, text size, margins between icons, text content etc.
I have tested some facebook screen also in the below devices and figure out that facebook screens are also looking different.
Facebook's icon size, text size, margins between icons, text content etc also looking different in the below devices with same resolution.
I have attached some screenshot of facebook. Kindly suggest me what I have to do so that my app will look same with same resolution in different manufacturer devices

**1. OnePlus 7T**

DISPLAY as below

- Resolution: 1080 x 2400 pixels, 20:9 ratio (~402 ppi density)
  Size:       6.55 inches, 103.6 cm2 (~86.5% screen-to-body ratio)
  Type:       Fluid AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
  Protection: Corning Gorilla Glass 5, HDR10+, 90Hz refresh rate

**2. Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime**

DISPLAY  as below

- Resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~401 ppi density)
  Size:       5.5 inches, 83.4 cm2 (~73.3% screen-to-body ratio)
  Type:       PLS TFT capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
  Protection: Corning Gorilla Glass (market dependent)

In OnePlus7t the icons, contents and margins are looking small in comparison to Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kke3.png) [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVath.png) [Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvSaE.png) [Screen 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMzlp.png)

Comment: You said it yourself, One Plus has more screen-to-body ratio and a better resolution than Samsung and even though its not a huge number , it clearly makes a big difference

Comment: But both devices have  same width : 1080 pixels

Comment: The screen size is measured diagonally not vertically, this may be why you are getting the difference